# Track http requests from android native browser

Tags: android

Is it possible to track/view the list of http requests made from a webpage on Android browser?(something similar to firebug's net panel)
I have tried adding firebug-lite but it doesn't seem to have net panel.
Also looked at weinre but not very clear as to how I can use it.
Prefer avoiding network capture.Hence not leaning towards wireshark/apache logs.
Is it possible to log it into logcat?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want this for debugging purposes, I think the simplest way to do it is to create a small app that loads your website in a [`WebView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) and, through the use of [`WebViewClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) (specifically the `onLoadResource` method) and possibly [`WebChromeClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html) logs all the requests that are made on the page.